# Is it OK to block the thread started by @Scheduled in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, spring-webflux

When you use @Scheduled annotation on a method in Spring WebFlux, it is executed on a thread called something like "scheduled-1". Can you use blocking APIs on such threads? Or do you still have to offload expensive tasks or IO to a thread pool?

Comment: WebFlux only applies to your web stack.  Your `@Scheduled` methods are invoked by the scheduler, not via an http request so you can write these without concerns about blocking.

Comment: Basically it is okay, as described in the comment above , but there are some nuances if you have a reactive chain in the method annotated @Scheduled annotation. You can see more details in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77702657/14183092